# Signal Bus error (7)

Tags: apache, magento, nginx

For a number of months now one of our client sites has been suffering Signal Bus Error (7) issues; as a heavy traffic site, the error has been known to be seen 100s of times a day.

On the front-end of the site, it shows up a 502 Gateway Error, primarily as we have Nginx running in tandem with Apache.

Our hosting provider has checked the server hardware and carried out a re-install of Apache, but the issues continue.

When the site was suspended; the errors stopped; bringing that site out of maintenance meant the errors popping up again.

Based on experience does this mean that this is a site code level issue and if so what is the recommended way to source the issue on a Magento site? Or could this be related to something like APC?

For reference we are running a Centos 5.8 server, with 16 CPU Cores and 32GB memory. We are running PHP 5.3.18 with Ion Cube Loader & Zend Engine. The site on the server is also using APC.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated; happy to provide more information.

Comment: I am aware that others have posted about this issue on Stackoverflow and elsewhere but so far we have not been able to find a resolution apart from hiding it behind Apache so the front-end errors decline to come throught.